# How can I catch " - Started abcApplication in 12.49 seconds " event?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web

Language:Java, Framework:Springboot, application-name:abcApplication
"21:47:32.133 [main] INFO  c.c.abc.abcApplication - Started abcApplication in 12.49 seconds (JVM running for 8.467)"

I am developing a web application with Springboot.
The springboot-application outputs the above message when the application starts up successfully. How can I handle this event? I would like to do something when the application's initialization is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is ContextRefreshedEvent, you can create a class and make it component and implement  ApplicationListener

```
@Component
public class ServerReadyClass implements  ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to ApplicationReadyEvent too.

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfiguration {
    private static final Logger log = 
   LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectConfiguration.class);

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    log.info("hello world, I have just started up");
  }
}
```